# Can I send a different header than 404 on my "custom 404' page in an apache server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

Example:

On the custom 404 script/page I want to check the requested uri against a list and redirect the user to that page if the requested uri doesn't exist.

I may send a 301 or a 302 depending on the content in the uri.

EDIT:

Here's the new idea: put the 404 error document in a new directory eg /errors/.  In that directory put the .htaccess with 4500 301 redirects. That way the 301 redirects are not processed on every root page, but only when a page is not found.

Please comment if this makes sense.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to define the redirect rules inside an .htaccess/httpd.conf file? (assuming this because the question is tagged with `htaccess`)

Comment: We are implementing 4500 301 redirects and this is stated to be far too many in a few threads here on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is stopping you from using the .htaccess file in the root directory?

Comment: @SalmanA Advice here on stackoverflow not to put so many 301 redirects in the root for performance reasons.  We are going to do that barring another solution. Our first attempt, using a Wordpress redirect failed - server couldn't handle the load.

Comment: Performance impact for that many redirects using htaccess is because the file is parsed for every request. You could put them in the httpd.conf file - so it would be loaded in memory on apache startup.

Comment: @fateddy is this considered the "best practice" - we've had differing opinions on this. Sounds like a great solution.

Comment: @ssaltman an alternate solution would be to use a PHP file as a 404 handler. You can write few lines of code to check the URL and either send a 301 or 404 response. And you can do database lookups instead of using hardcoding URLs in configuration files.

Comment: @SalmanA Which is better? httpd.config or custom php 404 script? Any guesses?

Comment: Cannot say about better. But PHP script would be my choice because it a more configurable and manageable solution. Not many web hosting providers allow you to edit httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

That many redirects i would definitely put in the httpd.conf/apache.conf. I would also suggest to redirect with a 301 status code (instead of delivering a 404 and then redirect as you outlined in your question). That said - there is one exceptional case: if there is a chance to map those 4500 redirects using regexp - you could switch back to htaccess again...